# SoapUI + Groovy + RESTService + Access authorization for 3 different URLs

Tags: rest, groovy, authorization, soapui

SoapUI + Groovy + RESTService

In my project, I have 3 different environments: Test1, Test2 and Test3. And now I have 3 different URLs, test data, and authorization. I am able to achieve different test data with respect to URL using groovy.

**Now facing problem in Authorization** How to change the authorization depending upon the URL?

Authorization is mentioned in Authorization box i.e. username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in SoapUI open source it is not available but in SoapUI Pro there is a feature called 'Environments' - which is exactly for this purpose. You can set URLs, DB connections, Authorization for different environments and then you can run the test suite for a particular environment.